# Integration multiple internet connections ISPUnity vs Ubuntu Bonding

Tags: networking, internet, routing, network-bonding

I have Ubuntu 13.04 with 2 ethernet cards and a WiFi card. I also have 3 ISP connections. I have to configure linux to use all 3 connections.
My main concern is to increase outgoing bandwidth (FTP traffic) for Ubuntu.

I found 2 possible solutions:

**Ubuntu Bonding**

Bonding, also called port trunking or link aggregation means combining several network interfaces (NICs) to a single link, providing either high-availability, load-balancing, maximum throughput, or a combination of these. See Wikipedia for details.

[UbuntuBonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding)

**IspUnity**

Open source framework, built to integrate (load balance & failover) multiple internet connections simultaneously. The project was started on 14th February 2012 by Arun Tomar, and has been since extended by team of collaborators.

[article about ISPUnity](http://theforevernoob.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/ispunity/)

**If you did integration of multiple internet connections can you please give recommendation which method is preferred or answer any of the following questions:**

- How good it works? Are you satisfied by result?
- Which particular method you selected and why?
- Any possible disadvantages which you see in the proposed solutions.
- If you can tell pros and cons of every solution it will be fantastic!

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**
After googling for hours I found [very usefull article](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) how to configure system to use 2 or 3 connections without link bonding. As temporary solution it works for me, but the main question is still very important.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why you have been down-voted, but it may be because the question is asking for opinions/experience. I would vote your question up if you rephrased the question to be more objective. It is a valid question, but subjective questions are frowned upon in stackexchange. I hope this helps ;)

Comment: @bntser Thank you! Your feedback was useful. I updated my questions. Sorry if some of my sentences are not clear, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Bonding is something completely unrelated to what you're trying to achieve, given the details.

Comment: You need a more network biased product for this. Take a look at http://pfsense.org This Firewall/Gateway can handle multiple connections and networks and is able to use all three providers at once.